# Viewport Shadow change Angle?

Tags: 3d-view, light

What determines the cast shadow in Viewpoint Shading and how to change the shadow angle? [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the shadow angle with the gizmo that comes up when you click on the cogwheel besides the shadow settings field in the viewport shading options. You need to click-and-drag on the gizmo to move the light direction.

Some might say it's a bit impractical when trying to get a precise angle.

If the lighting gizmo is fully white, it means the light casting the shadow comes from the -Y axis at a 0° angle. If only the top part is illuminated, there is no shadow since the light comes from the top. If the light illuminates the gizmo from the bottom, there will be only shadow.

[image]